# TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, exception

why does it throw the exception TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable? how can i fix this? hope you can help me
import random

```
enemies = ["Scorpion","Zombie","Spider","Bat","Boar"]   
enemy = enemies(random.choice[enemies])
```

Comment: It should be ``random.choice(enemies)``. Note the parentheses instead of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Round parentheses after a word are for function calls (`some_func()`), square brackets after a word are for indexing sequences or mappings (`some_dict[some_key]`). To fix this, simply replace your code by:

```
enemy = random.choice(enemies)
```